# How to Lambdify a multivariate sympy expression for numeric integration efficiently

Tags: python, sympy, numerical-integration

I have this very complex symbolic function of three variables, f(x,y,z), which I need to evaluate over a point in z and integrate over all the domain in x and y.

Summarizing, I've been using:

```
f_substituted=f.subs(z,valueforz)

f_numeric=lambdify([x,y].f_substituted)

#and then, integrate it a la Riemann (dblquad does not converge), by doing:

N=1000
q = np.linspace(-10, 10, N)
p = np.linspace(-10, 10, N)
dS=(q[1]-q[0])*(p[1]-p[0])
q, p = np.meshgrid(q, p) #I meshgrid to have a 2D grid for integration.

#I define a dataframe here because I have seen it is quicker than vectorizing the expression
df = pd.DataFrame({'Q':np.concatenate(q),'P':np.concatenate(p)})
integral=sum((rho_dot_00_x(df['Q'],df['P'])).dropna()).real*dS
```

My problem is that it works really slowly and I cannot make work ufuncify, or theano.

Also, I tried to lambdify using "numpy" argument, but it ran way slowlier (I thought it should be quicker than math).
I also tried evalf after the substitution, like this:

```
f_substituted=f.subs(z,valueforz).evalf()
```

but it was even slower.

Any help to make the numeric evaluation quicker would be welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't expect much help with such a vague question.  If `f` is complex I don't think I want to see it, but without seeing it's hard to say how `lambdify` has translated it.  Normally `lambdify` produces a `numpy` compatible version, though it's often rather dumb `numpy`; `lambdify` does not have deep knowledge.  `help(f_numeric)` shows what it has produced.  I don't know what `f_numeric` is.  And don't understand the point to using the dataframe.